# R Data.Table Join - Transform 'Missing' from NA to a Default Value

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to join two data tables.  The first (called 'left' below) has a set of keys (column 'k').  The second ('right') has a similar set of keys along with values for each key.  I want to update the 'left' data in-place so that it has the value from 'right' where it exists.  But in the case that it does not exist, a default value rather than NA should be populated.

I created a function 'default' that will replace NAs with a default value.

```
default <- function(value, default) {
    value[is.na(value)] <- default
    return(value)
}
```

I don't understand why the following does not work.

```
left <- data.table(k=c(1,2,3,4,NA), key="k")
right <- data.table(k=c(1,2), value=c("a","b"), key="k")
left[right, value := default(value,"none")]
```

Actual result...

```
> left
    k value
1: NA    NA
2:  1     a
3:  2     b
4:  3    NA
5:  4    NA
```

Expected result...

```
    k value
1: NA    none
2:  1     a
3:  2     b
4:  3    none
5:  4    none
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: take a look at `left[right]`, that should make clear to you why your approach didn't work

Comment: I'd just do `right[left][is.na(value), value := "none"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
right[left, list(value=default(value,"none"))]
```

Which gives :

```
    k value
1: NA  none
2:  1     a
3:  2     b
4:  3  none
5:  4  none
```

Your solution doesn't work because when you do `value := default(value,"none")`, the `default` function is only applied to the `value` column of `right`, ie `default(c("a","b"),"none")`. The `value` column is then updated with the result of the function for the lines who have a `value` before the join. The other `left`rows, who don't have any corresponding row in `right`, get a `NA` instead.

Sorry, not sure my explanation is very clear...

Comment: If I take this approach, then I am making a copy of the data, correct?

Comment: @NickAllen Yes, if by that you mean that in memory you will have both `left`, `right` and `right[left,...]` data tables.